# innerHTML insertar en html

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Quisiera insertar esos valores en html pero no me reconoce el ${} como codigo js alguna solucion?

```
const taskList = document.getElementById("task-list").innerHTML = 
"<div class='tasks'><div class='taskbody'><strong>Name Class</strong>: ${task.nameclass}  
<strong>Task Name</strong>: ${Task.nametask}  
<strong>description</strong>: ${Task.description}   
<strong>value</strong>: ${Task.value}   
<strong>date</strong>: ${Task.date} </div></div>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Para usar [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), la cadena de texto tiene que estar entre las comillas del acento grave: `` ` ``.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const taskList = document.getElementById("task-list").innerHTML = 
`<div class='tasks'><div class='taskbody'><strong>Name Class</strong>: ${task.nameclass}  
<strong>Task Name</strong>: ${Task.nametask}  
<strong>description</strong>: ${Task.description}   
<strong>value</strong>: ${Task.value}   
<strong>date</strong>: ${Task.date} </div></div>`;
```